# c++ SAT score reader assignment, compute standard deviation bug

Tags: c++, function, math, netbeans, dev-c++

I'm working on a program that reads 20 SAT scores. The scores will be read and stored into a 2D array. I've wrote two methods that I believe are the source of my problems. One I know for sure is the  compute STD function. I got the error message:

1 [main] satscores_proj1 1920 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to satscores_proj1.exe.stackdump

I'm using netbeans with the cygwin compiler package, but when I tried to run this with DevC++, this message popped up:

C:\Dev-Cpp\HW Assignments\satScores.cpp In function `void compute_std(int (*)[2], int, int, double&, double&)' call of overloaded`pow(int, int)' is ambiguous

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int sat[10][2], mathAvg, verbAvg;
    double mathStd, verbStd;

    void describe_program();
    void read_scores(int sat[10][2]);
    void compute_means(int sat[10][2], int& mathAvg, int& verbAvg);
    void compute_std(int sat[10][2],int mathAvg, int verbAvg, double& mathStd, double& verbStd) ;
    void show_results(int sat[10][2], int mathAvg, int verbAvg, double mathStd,  double verbstd);
    bool again();

    describe_program();
    read_scores(sat);
    compute_means(sat, mathAvg, verbAvg);
    compute_std(sat, mathAvg, verbAvg,  mathStd, verbStd);
    //show_results(sat, mathAvg, verbAvg, mathStd, verbStd);
    //again();
    return 0;
}

/*
 * 
 */

void compute_means(int sat[10][2], int& mathAvg, int& verbAvg)
{
    int mathScoreSum =0;
    int mathCount = 0;
    int verbScoreSum = 0;
    int verbCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)    
    {
        for(int j = 0; i<2; j++)
        {
            if(j==0){
                mathScoreSum += sat[i][j];
                mathCount++;
            }

            else{
                verbScoreSum += sat[i][j];
                verbCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    mathAvg = mathScoreSum / mathCount;
    verbAvg = verbScoreSum / verbCount;
}


void compute_std(int sat[10][2],int mathAvg, int verbAvg, double& mathStd, double& verbStd) 
{
    double mathVariance = 0;
    double verbVariance = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)    
    {
        for(int j = 0; i<2; j++)
        {

            if(j==0){
                mathVariance += pow((sat[i][j] - mathAvg), 2);
            }

            else{
                verbVariance += pow((sat[i][j] - mathAvg), 2);
            }

            mathStd = sqrt(mathVariance/9);
            verbStd = sqrt(verbVariance/9);
        }
    }
}
```

Is anyone familiar with these two errors?

Comment: Time to load up your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your segmentation fault is caused by `for(int j=0;i<2;j++)`  Note the `i`.  Obvious if you use a debugger.  Use a debugger :)

The compilation error is caused by multiple declarations of the function `pow`.  I'd try doing `::pow(`etc...  You can also do explicit casts like `(double)variable` to eliminate overloading as a concern.

Also, you shouldn't use a loop for code that never executes the same code twice:

```
    for(int j = 0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if(j==0){
            mathScoreSum += sat[i][j]; //<--first, j is 0
            mathCount++;
        }

        else{
            verbScoreSum += sat[i][j]; //<--second, j is 1
            verbCount++;
        }
    }
```

should be:

```
mathScoreSum += sat[i][0]; //<--first iteration of loop
mathCount++; //<--first iteration of loop
verbScoreSum += sat[i][1]; //<--second iteration of loop
verbCount++; //<--second iteration of loop
```

(Alternately, you could make `ScoreSum[2]` and `Count[2]` instead of your current 4 target variables and assign to those within the loop.)

Here's a full example of removing an unnecessary j loop:

```
void compute_std(int sat[10][2],int mathAvg, int verbAvg, double& mathStd, double& verbStd)
{
    double mathVariance = 0;
    double verbVariance = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        mathVariance += pow((sat[i][0] - mathAvg), 2);
        verbVariance += pow((sat[i][1] - verbAvg), 2);
    }
    mathStd = sqrt(mathVariance/9);
    verbStd = sqrt(verbVariance/9);
}
```

Comment: which are you refering to? don't i need the for loops in order to loop through the array in order to and to increment the count and add up all the mathScoreSums and verbScoreSums? I agree with you on ScoreSum[2] and Count[2] but still, I don't understand why i dont need the for loops.

Comment: @DarnellMcdonald  I'm referring to the j loop I quoted.  It only has two iterations...`0` and `1`...and executes different code for them (because of your if statement).  Do you see how the "should be" code does the *exact* same thing?  Your other j loop can go away too.

Comment: @DarnellMcdonald - I added some comments to my answer to hopefully clarify for you.

Comment: Also your `verbVariance +=` is using `mathAvg` instead of `verbAvg`

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that it is a double array. You need to loop through the double array, hence the j loop. I literally just tested every facet of the program and it works like a charm WITH the j loop. Sent the info to a text file and everything WITH the j loop

Comment: @DarnellMcdonald - `array[i][0] = 0; array[i][1] = 0;` is identical to `for(int j=0;j<2;j++){array[i][j] =0;}`  The loop will **work**, it just makes no sense to use a loop there.  (To clarify, I mean it makes no sense in the code above.  The loop in this comment is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

You are `using namespace std` which is creating a potential conflict when trying to distinguish between the `std::pow` function and the `pow` function from `#include <cmath>`.